# Which one is it more correct and natural to say: "talk over text," "talk via text" or "talk through text"?

Tags: prepositions

Would you tell me which one is it more correct and natural to say: *talk over text*, *talk via text* or *talk through text*? For example:

> I can't call you now, but we can talk **over** text.
>
> I can't call you now, but we can talk **via** text.
>
> I can't call you now, but we can talk **through** text.

Comment: I can't call you now, but we can text.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Let's say the context is a call center representative is talking to a client. Which one would I use in this sentence: "We'll send you the instructions for how to set it up over/through/via text"?

Comment: We will send it by text.